# Git log with version numbers

Tags: git, jenkins, logging

I'm trying to generate a readme file which looks as following:

```
not released yet
30c9474 myname 2018-08-23   Feature 1337

v1.0.76
420368f myname 2018-08-22   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy again

v1.0.75
be05539 myname 2018-08-16   Feature 2833
838c158 myname 2018-08-16   Fixed bug 9128
6fa061a myname 2018-08-14   Feature 8832

v1.0.74
21903f2 myname 2018-08-11   Some stuff
57f1a2f myname 2018-08-05   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy
```

this is how I generate my readmefile with jenkins currently:

```
node('master') {
    def artifactConfig = [
        version: '1.0.'+env.BUILD_NUMBER,
    ]

    try {
        // ######################################## Commit stage ######################################
        stage('Create Changelog stage') {
            // needs to be checked out again, because by default on master the sources are checkout out to ${WORKSPACE}@script in scripted pipeline
            checkout scm

            // the Changelog will be created here
            sh 'git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --pretty=format:"%d%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short --all | sed "s/^ *([^)]*)/\\n&\\n/;1i (not released yet)" > releasenotes.md'

            sh 'git config --global --unset-all core.editor && git config --global core.editor $(which vim)'

            sh 'git add releasenotes.md &&' +
                'git tag -a version/' + artifactConfig.version + ' -m "Version version/' + artifactConfig.version + ' created" &&' +
                'git commit -C HEAD --amend --no-edit &&' +
                'git push -f origin version/' + artifactConfig.version
        }
    } catch (exception) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw exception
    }
}
```

That creates a readme file in a versioned branch.
My problem is that I don't know how I can put that file together as my example. All I figured out is how to generate a readme file like:

```
30c9474 myname 2018-08-23   Feature 1337
420368f myname 2018-08-22   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy again
be05539 myname 2018-08-16   Feature 2833
838c158 myname 2018-08-16   Fixed bug 9128
6fa061a myname 2018-08-14   Feature 8832
21903f2 myname 2018-08-11   Some stuff
57f1a2f myname 2018-08-05   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy
```

---

Edit:
This is how my network graph looks like:
[image: Network Graph]
With the help of jthill I changed my git log line to this:

```
sh 'git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short | sed "s/^ *([^)]*)/\\n&\\n/;1i (not released yet)" > releasenotes.md'
```

but the result looks like this now:

```
(not released yet)
30c9474 myname 2018-08-23   Feature 1337
420368f myname 2018-08-22   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy again
be05539 myname 2018-08-16   Feature 2833
838c158 myname 2018-08-16   Fixed bug 9128
6fa061a myname 2018-08-14   Feature 8832
21903f2 myname 2018-08-11   Some stuff
57f1a2f myname 2018-08-05   Changed Jenkinsfile.groovy
```

which looks better, but it's still not what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data you need in the sequence you need with

```
git log --date=short --pretty='%d%h %an %ad   %s'
```

from there it's straight text munging with your favorite tool.  If you don't need it too pretty, piping it through

```
sed 's/^ *([^)]*)/\n&\n/;1i (not released yet)'
```

will do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use it as following: sh 'git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=short | sed "s/^ *([^)]*)/\n&\n/;1i (not released yet)" > releasenotes.md' ---
But Jenkins says:sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I'd use single quotes or double the backslashes, the 13th char is the first backslash and it looks as if something's doing the `\n` escape processing before `sed` sees it.

Comment: Thank you! That helped but I fear the result is not what I expected. I edited my question to provide some more information.

Comment: Since you've got your candidate tags on side branches your log command won't list them at all since they're not in any listed tip's (you've listed only, you're only searching back from, `HEAD`) ancestry.  Tell log to also look at the candidate tags you're interested in, brute force would be `--all --since=` your base commit's date.

Comment: When I add --all, then the side branches are included but everything is still listed under "(not released yet)". I do not understand what 
    sed 's/^ *([^)]*)/\n&\n/;1i (not released yet)'
does.

Comment: Look at the output before and after the sed. The difference is what it does.  btw, instead of `--since=`, `--ancestry-path` gets precisely the commits you want.  to get the sequencing exactly right for this task `--topo-order`  might do it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to include that tag/version number in `git log --format=...` itself.

It is possible with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021, 7 years later), "[`git log --format=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25f9326561292b45311c60879d9bc08618727973/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L2)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup>" learned the "`%(describe)`" placeholder.

See [commit 9609972](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96099726ddb00b45135964220ce56468ba9fe184), [commit 273c990](https://github.com/git/git/commit/273c9901c2ebfb2dae0c52de912bf3f57be19aac), [commit 09fe8ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09fe8ca92e4f0269bd7914b5010731a09948abf0) (28 Feb 2021), and [commit b081547](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b081547ec1de57162f2c1c7748aa09c861413d34), [commit 15ae82d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15ae82d5d6ccdcad00aeb456ff512d3031f03039) (14 Feb 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 25f9326](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25f9326561292b45311c60879d9bc08618727973), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15ae82d5d6ccdcad00aeb456ff512d3031f03039): add %(describe)
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Eli Schwartz</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Add a format placeholder for describe output.
>
> Implement it by actually calling [`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15ae82d5d6ccdcad00aeb456ff512d3031f03039/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup>, which is simple and guarantees correctness.
> It's intended to be used with `$Format:...$` in files with the attribute `export-subst` and `git archive`.
> It can also be used with [`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15ae82d5d6ccdcad00aeb456ff512d3031f03039/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> etc., even though that's going to be slow due to the fork for each commit.

And:

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b081547ec1de57162f2c1c7748aa09c861413d34): add merge and exclude options to `%(describe)`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Allow restricting the tags used by the placeholder `%(describe)` with the options match and exclude.
> E.g.
> the following command describes the current commit using official version tags, without those for release candidates:
>
> ```
> $ git log -1 --format='%(describe:match=v[0-9]*,exclude=*rc*)'
> ```

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b081547ec1de57162f2c1c7748aa09c861413d34/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L211-L221):

> '`%(describe[:options])`':: human-readable name, like
> [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe); empty string for undescribable commits.
> The `describe` string may be followed by a colon and zero or more
> comma-separated options.
>
> - '`match=<pattern>`': Only consider tags matching the given
>   `glob(7)` pattern, excluding the "refs/tags/" prefix.
> - '`exclude=<pattern>`': Do not consider tags matching the given
>   `glob(7)` pattern, excluding the "`refs/tags/`" prefix.

Warning:

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/273c9901c2ebfb2dae0c52de912bf3f57be19aac): document multiple %(describe) being inconsistent
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Each `%(describe)` placeholder is expanded using a separate [`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/273c9901c2ebfb2dae0c52de912bf3f57be19aac/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> call.
> Their outputs depend on the tags present at the time, so there's no consistency guarantee.
> Document that fact.

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/273c9901c2ebfb2dae0c52de912bf3f57be19aac/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L215-L217):

> Descriptions can be inconsistent when tags are added or removed at
> the same time.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), extend "[`git log --format=%(describe)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ba65f4ac321d628d754b3e5494a348a2106c03a/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L2)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup>" placeholder to allow passing selected command-line options to the underlying "[`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ba65f4ac321d628d754b3e5494a348a2106c03a/Documentation/git-describe.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> command.

See [commit eccd97d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eccd97d0b02a87db0b0e828dd4f0b441c5462a9c), [commit 1d517ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d517ceab98fd5c3c1a8fb6ef575b44c31ea7a9e), [commit 3c6eb4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c6eb4ec50d9a4a9017fb8c1f220d12dceb206b1) (31 Oct 2021) by [Eli Schwartz (`eli-schwartz`)](https://github.com/eli-schwartz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6ba65f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ba65f4ac321d628d754b3e5494a348a2106c03a), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eccd97d0b02a87db0b0e828dd4f0b441c5462a9c): add `abbrev` option to `%(describe)`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eli Schwartz</sup>

> The `%(describe)` placeholder by default, like [`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eccd97d0b02a87db0b0e828dd4f0b441c5462a9c/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup>, uses a seven-character abbreviated commit object name.
> This may not be sufficient to fully describe all commits in a given repository, resulting in a placeholder replacement changing its length because the repository grew in size.
> This could cause the output of [`git-archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eccd97d0b02a87db0b0e828dd4f0b441c5462a9c/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> to change.
>
> Add the `--abbrev` option to `git describe` to the placeholder interface in order to provide tools to the user for fine-tuning project defaults and ensure reproducible archives.
>
> One alternative would be to just always specify `--abbrev=40` but this may be a bit too biased...

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eccd97d0b02a87db0b0e828dd4f0b441c5462a9c/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L225-L228):

> ** '`abbrev=<number>`': Instead of using the default number of hexadecimal digits
> (which will vary according to the number of objects in the repository with a
> default of 7) of the abbreviated object name, use  digits, or as many
> digits as needed to form a unique object name.

Example:

```
git log -1 --format="%(describe:abbrev=15)"
```